# Decomposing $\mathbb{R}^{8}$ Using an $8\times 8$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ an $8\times 8$ real matrix such that $A^{21}=I$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}^{8}$ can be written as the direct sum of $4$ two dimensional vector subspaces invariant under $A$, that is $\mathbb{R}^{8}=\mathbb{V}_{1} \oplus \mathbb{V}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{V}_{3} \oplus \mathbb{V}_{4}$ where $A(\mathbb{V}_{j}) \subset \mathbb{V}_{j}$.

Now, the easy way of doing this would be to show that $A$ is normal and then apply the structure theorem for normal operators, but I wasn't able to do it.

The other way I see is to write out $A$ in Jordan normal form, and show everything by hand, but that seems extremely time consuming.

So, what is the fastest way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about something:  how can an $8 \times 8$ matrix act on $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: I have fixed it :P

Comment: Ah, saw your edit!  So it *was* $\Bbb R^8$ after all.  Makes much more sense that way.  Thanks!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A$ need not be normal.

**Counterexample:** Take the block matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{B&I_2\\&I_2\\&&I_4}
$$
where $I_n$ is the size-$n$ identity matrix and
$$
B = \frac 12 \pmatrix{-1 & \sqrt 3\\ -\sqrt 3 & -1}
$$

**Hint:** Note that the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $x^{21} - 1$.  What does this tell you about the Jordan form of $A$?

In particular, note that $A$ must be diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$.  What can its eigenvalues complex be?

Comment: Ah, so I have to look at the cyclotomic polynomials then. Since the possible degrees of the characteristic polynomial is 8, it has to be a product of the 1st, 3rd, and 7th cyclotomic polynomials in some combination (since \Phi_{21} has too large a degree). Then I can look at the particular eigenvalues.

Comment: It's enough to note that the only possible eigenvalues are the roots of $x^{21} - 1$.  From there, consider the cases of when an eigenvalue is real and when it is complex separately.

Comment: So here is what I'm thinking. Well, the roots of the characteristic and minimal polynomials are the same except for multiplicities. Hence, if the characteristic polynomial is the product of the 3rd and 7th cyclotomic polynomials, it has 8 distinct roots which come in pairs of complex conjugates. Those can be arranged to give the 2D subspaces. Otherwise, it's a product of 4 copies of the 3rd cyclotomic polynomial, 8 copies of the (x-1) factor, or the 7th cyclotomic polynomial and two factors (x-1). Then you can look at the different possible Jordan blocks.

Comment: That sounds like it will work. An easier approach: because $A$ is real, any non-real eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs and therefore correspond to an invariant subspace of (even) dimension at least $2$. The smallest possible dimension of an invariant subspace of $A$ is $1$, corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: In fact, it's impossible to give the eigenspace corresponding to $1$ an odd dimension since all other eigenspaces must have even dimension, and the total of the dimensions must be $8$.